# Makefile issue in Creating Postgres Extension

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

My basic extension code is at location -> `/Users/spartacus/Desktop/GSoC/CODE/my_extension`

- **my_extension.control**

```
# my_extension.control
comment = 'Minimal Viable Product'
default_version = '1.0'
relocatable = true

# Installation script for version 1.0
# 1.0
# my_extension--1.0.sql
```

- **my_extension--1.0.sql**

```sql
-- my_extension--1.0.sql

-- Create necessary objects for version 1.0
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  -- Function logic goes here
END;
```

- **MakeFile**

```
DATA = my_extension--1.0.sql

PG_CONFIG  ?= pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

-- cd command to navigate to the directory where your extension files are located. After connecting to that location, executing the make command throws this error:

`make: Nothing to be done for 'all'`

-- After executing make install:

- `/bin/sh /opt/homebrew/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/opt/homebrew/share/postgresql/contrib'`
- `/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 .//my_extension--1.0.sql  '/opt/homebrew/share/postgresql/contrib/'`

-- Running psql;
Then after executing `CREATE EXTENSION my_extension;` This error occurs:

- `ERROR:  extension "my_extension" is not available`
- `DETAIL:  Could not open extension control file "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/share/postgresql/extension/my_extension.control": No such file or directory.`
- `HINT:  The extension must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running.`

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Your extension does not need a library so just put `.sql` and `.control`file into your extension folder

Comment: I need to use a Makefile, it's a part of the project I am currently pursuing.
I have already made a simple extension with a `.sql` and a `.control` file for them I copied the files to the directories. But I need to use the makefile to i install the control file remotely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Makefile` is lacking the entry

```
EXTENSION = my_extension
```

That's why `make install` doesn't copy the `*.control` file, and that's why `CREATE EXTENSION` fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Just a doubt, what does the `make: Nothing to be done for 'all' ` mean. 
Is it an error?

Comment: That you have no `MODULE` or other binary to build. You can go directly to the `make install` step.